# Download multiple files with one button primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

Is it possible to download multiple files at once using PrimeFaces `p:fileDownload`

What I had in mind would be like

```
  <p:commandButton value="Download All Documents" 
                             styleClass="GreenButton" 
                             icon="fa fa-download" 
                             title="Download all documents, generated and uploaded."
                             onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(null, hideLoader);"
                             update=":growl">
 <!-- code Here 
        < ui:repeat> p:downloadFile (file) </ui:repeat>
--> 
            </p:commandButton>
```

I have a list of documents that needs to be dynamically, the list will differ so should be dynamically. Is there a way to do this and so how?

Comment: Create a zip file containing all files

Comment: @JasperdeVries would this be the only way? had a zip file in mind

Comment: I would not annoy the user with multiple downloads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not annoy the user with multiple downloads. Just create a zip file containing your files.

See:

- [How to create a zip file of multiple image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546992/how-to-create-a-zip-file-of-multiple-image-files)

Comment: accepted this , link useful but know how to make a zip with multiple entries. Thanks :)